# Should my tests be creating db records for manditory associations?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, unit-testing, mocking

This is a best-practices kind of question: If my `Garden` has a required field of `user_id` should my tests be actually creating the `User` in the database, or is there a better approach?

I'm finding that in my controller's update tests I'm running into cases where I want to reuse my garden factory, but the garden factory creates the required user in the database and I'm running into unique constraint violations on duplicate emails.  So now I either need to make the factory generate unique emails or I need to learn how to mock up the associated record.

I guess the thing that really has me caught up short is that creating/updating a garden checks the database for the existence of the associated record.  I don't yet understand how I could shortcut that.  And I also don't know if that is necessary?  If I set up the database_cleaner gem to perform tests as database transactions by default, perhaps I don't have to worry about how many `User` records are being "written"?

Comment: It's better to have the associations present in db (atleast parent associations) If you are worried about manually generating unique records give `FactoryGirl` a try

Answer (score 0):

I would use [factory girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) for this its a good way to emulate the behavior of models and their associations. There are a few different ways to create factories that have set associations. You can create factories that will always create their associations. I personally prefer to create all instances of my factories separately as it gives me more flexibility,  that is not to say that there are not good use cases to do it otherwise.

```
#garden factory
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :garden do
      #you can choose which attributes to prepopulate for every garden
    end
  end

#garden factory
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
      #you can choose which attributes to prepopulate for every garden
    end
  end

#in your test
user1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: 'user1', role: 'farmer)
garden1 = FactoryGirl.create(:garden, name: 'garden1', flower_count: 6, user: user1)
```

Now you cn get much more complex but this is a simple exmaple you can go [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) for more pointers